# Wordpress site takes very long to load

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I have a website designed by an external vendor on Wordpress that is taking very long to load. The funny thing is that the page loaded ok on  their test servers, but it only became very slow when it was on our Azure host.

We have previously worked with them on another website, but didn't have any issues in the loading speeds of the website. On our end, we have set up our server settings to be exactly the same as the the first website, but it doesn't help.

Is there any other thing that we can check for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the test server a more powerful server? Depending on if you are in a shared environment or not, this could affect performance.

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the web server and database server being separate machines now rather than having 1 machine acting as both a web and database server in the testing environment? The number of separate database connections/queries will affect performance.

Comment: @BrandonWhite We are checking the possibility of the test server, just that because the other site loads fine both on their test and on our Azure environment..

Comment: @Nerdwood i did not consider the web and database servers being separate. number of connections are the same as for the other server, but i can follow up on the servers.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure Web apps to host your wordpress site and connect to MySQL hosted on other service.You can check the region of your Web Apps and MySQL Service. When we create a web app service, it required us to select a region which will decide which data center will host the web site.
So if your web site and MySQL server or your browsing areas are cross region, it may cost a lot loading time.

Also, I  recommend you refer to this blog about how to improve our website performance: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/

If you are hosting your wordpress site and MySQL server in an Azure VM, we can check the bottleneck of the application at the monitor tab of the azure manage portal. There are CPU Percentage, disk i/o and network metrics shown in timeline.

By the way, for website performance, you can try to use [Test a website's performance](http://www.webpagetest.org/) and find the large elapsed time of files for further optimization.

If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.